# php form processing not sending comment data

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created a form in html with .php form processing. It sends most of the data, but not the comment section, it gives the html part but not the comments. In the email I get it gives the section title but not the comments.

[image: email response.]

Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP form to email sample form</title>
<!-- define some style elements-->
<style>
label,a 
{
    font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 12px; 
}

</style>    
<!-- a helper script for vaidating the form-->
<script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>


<body>

<!-- Start code for the form-->
<form method="post" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email2.php">
<input name="first_name" type="text" tabindex="1" required id="First" placeholder="First Name" title="First and Last Name"  size="50"></p>
  <p><input name="last_name" type="text" tabindex="2" required id="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name" title="Last Name"  size="50"></p>

<p><input name="date" type="text" tabindex="3" required id="Date" placeholder="Date" title="Date"  size="50">
</p>

<p><input name="email" type="email" tabindex="4" required id="Email" placeholder="Email"  size="50"></p>
<p><input name="day_phone" type="tel" tabindex="5" required id="Day Phone" placeholder="Day Phone" title="Day Phone" size="50"></p>

<p><input name="evening_phone" type="tel" tabindex="5" required id="Evening Phone" placeholder="Evening Day Phone" title="Evening Day Phone" size="50"></p>
<h5>Property:
    <select name="property" size="1" tabindex="6" required id="Property" placeholder="Property" title="Property"> 
      <option value="Gan Aden, 441 Ash St. Willimantic">Gan Aden, 441 Ash St. Willimantic</option> 
      <option value="Gan Aden Too, 306 Ash St. Willimantic">Gan Aden Too, 306 Ash St. Willimantic</option> 
      <option value="Gan Aden South, 300 Windham Road, Willimantic">Gan Aden South, 300 Windham Road, Willimantic</option> 
      <option value="Gan Aden of Colchester, 385 South Main, Colchester">Gan Aden of Colchester, 385 South Main, Colchester</option> 
      <option value="Gan Aden Too of Colchester, Dogwood, Maple Lane, Colchester">Gan Aden Too of Colchester, Dogwood, Maple Lane, Colchester</option> 
      <option value="Gan Aden at Chestnut, 28 Chestnut Hill Rd, Colchester">Gan Aden at Chestnut, 28 Chestnut Hill Rd, Colchester</option> 
      <option value="Gan Aden Fields, 564 Norwich Ave, Colchester">Gan Aden Fields, 564 Norwich Ave, Colchester</option> 
      <option value="Stone Ridge Estates, 12 Dr. Manning Dr.,Lebanon">Stone Ridge Estates, 12 Dr. Manning Dr.,Lebanon</option> 
      <option value="Indian Ridge , 404 East Main, Jewett City">Indian Ridge , 404 East Main, Jewett City</option> 
      <option value="Mary Brown, 112 Brown Ave. Jewett City">Mary Brown, 112 Brown Ave. Jewett City</option> 
      <option value="Shady Lane, Cathcart Lane, Jewett City">Shady Lane, Cathcart Lane, Jewett City</option> 
      <option value="Pear Tree, 34 Brown Ave, Jewett City">Pear Tree, 34 Brown Ave, Jewett City</option> 
      <option value="Pleasant House, 260 Pleasant St. Willimantic">Pleasant House, 260 Pleasant St. Willimantic</option> 
      <option value="Village Heights, 55 Renee Drive, Colchester">Village Heights, 55 Renee Drive, Colchester</option> 
      <option value="Other Residence">Other Residence</option> 
      <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option> 
    </select></h5>

<p><input name="unit" type="text" tabindex="7" required id="Unit" placeholder="Unit" title="Unit"  size="50">
</p>

<p><textarea name="comments" tabindex="8" cols="50" rows="10" maxlength="150" form="maintenancefrom2" placeholder="Maintenance Problem"></textarea></p>

    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="submit">
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
// Code for validating the form
// Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
// for details
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("myemailform");
frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address"); 
</script>

</body>
```

Here is the .php

```
    <?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the     form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['first_name'];
$name = $_POST['last_name'];
$name = $_POST['date'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['day_phone'];
$name = $_POST['evening_phone'];
$name = $_POST['property'];
$name = $_POST['unit'];
$message = $_POST['comments'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'repair@mywebsite.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Maintenance Form submission";




   $email_body .= "Maintenance Form";
   $email_body .= "First Name: " .$_POST['first_name'];
   $email_body .= "Last Name: " .$_POST['last_name'];
   $email_body .= "Date: " .$_POST['date'];
   $email_body .= "Email: ".$_POST['email'];
   $email_body .= "Day Phone: " .$_POST['day_phone'];
   $email_body .= "Evening Phone: " .$_POST['evening_phone'];
   $email_body .= "Property: ".$_POST['property'];
   $email_body .= "Unit: ".$_POST['unit'];
   $email_body .= "Maintenance Problem: ".$_POST['comments'];






$to = "myname@gmail.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: confirmation.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
          '(%0A+)',
          '(%0D+)',
          '(%08+)',
          '(%09+)'
          );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Please post your form's markup here.

Comment: Why cast all of the POST array values to variables if you're not going to use the variables?

Comment: Rather than using a homemade filter for email, just use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Comment: Add a `print_r($_POST);` to the top of your PHP file and re-submit the form. Post the results here.

Comment: Your code is still vulnerable to email injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your form attribute on your textarea element doesn't match the name of your form:

```
<textarea name="comments" form="maintenancefrom2"></textarea>
```

Your form's opening tag:

```
<form method="post" name="myemailform">
```

So the value is not sent with the form submission.

Comment: Thank you I did fix that. However the email that I get has the comment section blank.

Comment: I took out the form="maintenanceform2" and that worked. Thank you. Could you also help me with adding some formatting to my email? Right now everything runs together in the email that I get. I added an image to how it comes throught in the original question. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You could add a new line at the beginning of each part (line):   `$email_body .= "\nMaintenance Form";` or where applicable.

Comment: You mean, $email_body .= "\nFirst Name: " .$_POST['first_name'];